# Send User-Initiated Email using Fuel C# SDK with Data Extension and Publication List

Tags: email, fuel-sdk, c#, dataextensions

I would like to send a user-initiated email using API calls through the Fuel C# SDK. The user-initiated emails have been set up using the UI and data extensions are used for the addressees. I chose to use a data extension so we have access to use a publication list. This publication list will be used by multiple sends since these emails will be for commercial purposes.

My questions are:

1. How do I add subscribers to the data extension and make sure that the email only goes to them and not to others previously listed in the data extension? (using the API)
2. How do I send the user-initiated email using the Fuel C# SDK?

My preference would have been to use triggered emails, but we cannot do that because we need to maintain separate publication lists for emails sent using other send profiles within the same business unit. We do not want recipients to unsubscribe from every commercial email sent from our business unit. We only want the recipients to be able to unsubscribe from the relevant emails.